# SpamAssassin coming back with zero scores

Tags: spamassassin

When I run tests (`spamassassin -t`) on obvious spam, I get results like this:

```
Content analysis details:   (2.0 points, 5.0 required)

 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
-0.0 NO_RELAYS              Informational: message was not relayed via SMTP
 0.0 T_TVD_MIME_NO_HEADERS  BODY: T_TVD_MIME_NO_HEADERS
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
 2.0 PYZOR_CHECK            Listed in Pyzor (http://pyzor.sf.net/)
-0.0 NO_RECEIVED            Informational: message has no Received headers
 0.0 T_REMOTE_IMAGE         Message contains an external image
```

It's clearly finding things wrong with it, but everything scores at 0 points for some reason (except Pyzor). Have I configured something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment `Informational: message was not relayed via SMTP` implies that the message your scanning has little or no useful header information.  Did you by any chance save or export the e-mail message, rather than working on the raw message in your Mailstore?

On testing with some of my higher scoring Spam after removing the `Received:` headers I get the same informational message and it typically results in a 10 point drop in the score SpamAssassin assigns...

Comment: No, but I am running amavis. So mail comes in on port 25, amavis checks it by fetching a SpamAssassin score, then passes it onto localhost port 10025 for delivery. That may be why. Maybe using `spamassassin -t` to test emails isn't reliable.

Comment: Also fishy, in another spamassassin test result: `0.2 BAYES_999    BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99.9 to 100% [score: 1.0000]`. If there's over a 99.9% probability it's spam, why would it assign such a low score of 0.2?